# How can I remove a stuck tub spigot?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

While trying to remove the child safety cover from my tub spigot I managed to shear off the plug mechanism that activates the shower.

The guy at the hardware store sold me a new spigot and now I need to remove the old one. I've tried twisting it, but it is stuck quite solidly and I can't seem to get it off. I don't care about the condition of the spigot when it is removed, just that is comes off without damaging the pipe underneath so that the new one can be screwed on.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (it's rather brute force, but functional):

- Take a small C-clamp (I had a 3" one laying around) and place it in the mouth of the spigot on the right hand side with the body of the clamp facing down.
- Tighten the clamp
- Twist the clamp counter clockwise using the body of the clamp as a gripping surface and leverage
- If it doesn't work try tapping the spigot with a hammer or mallet to jar it loose a bit then try the clamp again.

Note: this may damage the spigot a bit, it was useful to me as the spigot was already broken and all I had available was a hammer and a clamp.